# XSL ambiguous rule confusion

Tags: xml, xslt

I am receiving an ambiguous rule match error that is throwing me. This is the error:

```
Recoverable error 
  XTRE0540: Ambiguous rule match for
  /dmodule/content[1]/description[1]/levelledPara[2]/levelledPara[4]/table[1]
Matches both "table[parent::levelledPara] | table[parent::proceduralStep]" on line 3047 of
  file:/c:/users/c79460/AppData/Local/PWC%20PDF%20Generator/test3.xsl
and "table[not(parent::levelledPara)] | table[not(parent::proceduralStep)]" on line 2962
  of file:/c:/users/c79460/AppData/Local/PWC%20PDF%20Generator/test3.xsl
```

I do not see where there could be any ambiguity based on the two rules cited and the path it was matching. It seems obvious to me that this table has a levelledPara parent, so why would I get the the ambiguity with a rule match for not(parent::levelledPara)? I'm sure I am probably missing something ridiculously simple, hoping some fresh perspective will catch it. Is it simply because I have an "or" in the match statements using two different parent tags (levelledPara and proceduralStep)?

XSL:

```
<xsl:template match="table[not(parent::levelledPara)] | table[not(parent::proceduralStep)]">
    <xsl:variable name="TId" select="@id"/>
    <xsl:variable name="tCount">
        <xsl:number level="any" count="table" format="1"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" id="{$TId}" ><!--margin-left="-10mm" -->
        <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(1)"/>
        <fo:table-header>
            <fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-cell>
                    <xsl:if test="title/text()">
                        <!--border="1 solid black" --><fo:block keep-with-next="always" text-align="center" padding-top="8pt" padding-bottom="2pt" space-after="2pt" margin-left="-10mm">
                            <fo:inline font-style="italic">Table <xsl:value-of select="$tCount"/>
                                <xsl:value-of select="concat(' - ', ./title)"/></fo:inline>
                            <fo:retrieve-table-marker retrieve-class-name="tab-cont" 
                                retrieve-position-within-table="first-starting" 
                                retrieve-boundary-within-table="table"/>
                        </fo:block>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="not(title/text())">
                        <fo:block keep-with-next="always" text-align="center" space-after="2pt">
                            <fo:inline font-style="italic">Table <xsl:value-of select="$tCount"/>
                                </fo:inline>
                            <fo:retrieve-table-marker retrieve-class-name="tab-cont" 
                                retrieve-position-within-table="first-starting" 
                                retrieve-boundary-within-table="table"/>
                        </fo:block>
                    </xsl:if>
                </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
        </fo:table-header>
        <fo:table-body>
            <fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:marker marker-class-name="tab-cont"/>
                    <fo:block/>
                </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:marker marker-class-name="tab-cont">&#x00A0;- (Continued)</fo:marker>
                    <fo:block keep-with-previous="always">
                        <fo:marker marker-class-name="tab-cont">&#x00A0;- (Continued)</fo:marker>
                        <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%">
                            <xsl:for-each select="colspec">
                                <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(@colwidth)"/>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                            <fo:table-header>
                                <xsl:for-each select="./tgroup/thead/row">
                                    <fo:table-row>
                                        <xsl:apply-templates/>
                                    </fo:table-row>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </fo:table-header>
                            <fo:table-footer>
                                <fo:table-row>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="./tgroup/thead/row[1]/entry"><!--[position() &gt; 1]-->
                                        <fo:table-cell border-top-style="solid" border-top-color="black" border-collapse="collapse">
                                            <fo:block/>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </fo:table-row>
                            </fo:table-footer>
                            <fo:table-body>
                                <xsl:for-each select="./tgroup/tbody/row">
                                    <fo:table-row>
                                        <xsl:apply-templates/>
                                    </fo:table-row>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                                <xsl:if test="./tgroup/tfoot">
                                    <xsl:for-each select="./tgroup/tfoot/row">
                                        <fo:table-row>
                                            <xsl:apply-templates/>
                                        </fo:table-row>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </xsl:if>
                            </fo:table-body>
                        </fo:table>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
        </fo:table-body>
    </fo:table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="table[parent::levelledPara] | table[parent::proceduralStep]">
    <xsl:variable name="TId" select="@id"/>
    <xsl:variable name="tCount">
        <xsl:number level="any" count="table" format="1"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="93%" id="{$TId}" margin-left="-10mm"><!--margin-left="-10mm" -->
        <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(1)"/>
        <fo:table-header>
            <fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-cell>
                    <xsl:if test="title/text()">
                        <!--border="1 solid black" --><fo:block keep-with-next="always" text-align="center" padding-top="8pt" padding-bottom="2pt" space-after="2pt" margin-left="-10mm">
                            <fo:inline font-style="italic">Table <xsl:value-of select="$tCount"/>
                                <xsl:value-of select="concat(' - ', ./title)"/></fo:inline>
                            <fo:retrieve-table-marker retrieve-class-name="tab-cont" 
                                retrieve-position-within-table="first-starting" 
                                retrieve-boundary-within-table="table"/>
                        </fo:block>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="not(title/text())">
                        <fo:block keep-with-next="always" text-align="center" space-after="2pt">
                            <fo:inline font-style="italic">Table <xsl:value-of select="$tCount"/>
                            </fo:inline>
                            <fo:retrieve-table-marker retrieve-class-name="tab-cont" 
                                retrieve-position-within-table="first-starting" 
                                retrieve-boundary-within-table="table"/>
                        </fo:block>
                    </xsl:if>
                </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
        </fo:table-header>
        <fo:table-body>
            <fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:marker marker-class-name="tab-cont"/>
                    <fo:block/>
                </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:marker marker-class-name="tab-cont">&#x00A0;- (Continued)</fo:marker>
                    <fo:block keep-with-previous="always">
                        <fo:marker marker-class-name="tab-cont">&#x00A0;- (Continued)</fo:marker>
                        <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%">
                            <xsl:for-each select="colspec">
                                <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(@colwidth)"/>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                            <fo:table-header>
                                <xsl:for-each select="./tgroup/thead/row">
                                    <fo:table-row>
                                        <xsl:apply-templates/>
                                    </fo:table-row>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </fo:table-header>
                            <fo:table-footer>
                                <fo:table-row>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="./tgroup/thead/row[1]/entry"><!--[position() &gt; 1]-->
                                        <fo:table-cell border-top-style="solid" border-top-color="black" border-collapse="collapse">
                                            <fo:block/>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </fo:table-row>
                            </fo:table-footer>
                            <fo:table-body>
                                <xsl:for-each select="./tgroup/tbody/row">
                                    <fo:table-row>
                                        <xsl:apply-templates/>
                                    </fo:table-row>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                                <xsl:if test="./tgroup/tfoot">
                                    <xsl:for-each select="./tgroup/tfoot/row">
                                        <fo:table-row>
                                            <xsl:apply-templates/>
                                        </fo:table-row>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </xsl:if>
                            </fo:table-body>
                        </fo:table>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
        </fo:table-body>
    </fo:table>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `levelledPara/table` matches both `table[parent::levelledPara]` and `table[not(parent::proceduralStep)]`. You probably meant to write:

```
<xsl:template match="table[not(parent::levelledPara or parent::proceduralStep)]">
```

instead of:

```
<xsl:template match="table[not(parent::levelledPara)] | table[not(parent::proceduralStep)]">
```

> Is it simply because I have an "or" in the match statements using two
>   different parent tags (levelledPara and proceduralStep)?

But you don't have an `or`. You have the `union` operator. And you are unioning tables, not their parents. This would have worked, too:

```
<xsl:template match="table[not(parent::levelledPara | parent::proceduralStep)]">
```

Comment: Mixed up those two, feel little dumb for that. That fixed the table issue. I also received an ambiguity for children of the table (entry elements) that I managed to resolve. Thanks for the help.